# Какие есть цвета следов черепашки в Python3? Можно ли писать их в системе RGB?

Tags: python-3.5, цвета, модули

> Задача:
>   Найти способ рисовки черепахой наибольшего количества цветов.

Делаю программу. Подключил модуль `turtle` и ищу способ передать новый цвет для черепашки (так как мне не достаточно цветов `yellow, green, red`и т.д.). Такой вопрос: Можно ли в какой-либо другой кодировке цветов передать какой-нибудь оттенок, которого нет в стандартых цветах? Если нет, то есть ли список **всех** цветов для черепашки?

Comment: `all_colors = itertools.product(range(256), repeat=3)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все ответ найден. Функция  `help(turtle.color)` дала следующую информацию о цвете следов черепашки:

```
Help on function color in module turtle:

color(*args)
Return or set the pencolor and fillcolor.

Arguments:
Several input formats are allowed.
They use 0, 1, 2, or 3 arguments as follows:

color()
    Return the current pencolor and the current fillcolor
    as a pair of color specification strings as are returned
    by pencolor and fillcolor.
color(colorstring), color((r,g,b)), color(r,g,b)
    inputs as in pencolor, set both, fillcolor and pencolor,
    to the given value.
color(colorstring1, colorstring2),
color((r1,g1,b1), (r2,g2,b2))
    equivalent to pencolor(colorstring1) and fillcolor(colorstring2)
    and analogously, if the other input format is used.

If turtleshape is a polygon, outline and interior of that polygon
is drawn with the newly set colors.
For mor info see: pencolor, fillcolor

Example:
>>> color('red', 'green')
>>> color()
('red', 'green')
>>> colormode(255)
>>> color((40, 80, 120), (160, 200, 240))
>>> color()
('#285078', '#a0c8f0')
```

Из чего следует что цвета можно записывать HEX-формате (а это мне и надо))).